# SQL Check if value is between multiple times periods

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to setup a query to check if the date/time from my record is within a valid time and not during a scheduled break. I have a table that has multiple start/end times for break start/end times and I would like to check if the current datetime is between any of the matching rows?

Not sure how to do this as the QTY of rows might change as the business grows?

**Breaks Table**

- BreakID - INT
- BreakStart - Time
- BreakEnd - Time

I would like then lookup if the current Value is in a break. The source table will be of Date/Time value, I would like an output in the formate

- RecordDateTime - Date/Time
- ValidShiftTime - INT (0 if the RecordDateTime falls within the time periods in the Breaks Table)

I'm not sure where to start to do this in SQL and if it's even possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The most obvious way might be to do an inner join on the breaks table (WHERE x BETWEEN BreakStart AND BreakEnd)... but I guess you already tried this?

Comment: I have a static version where I do a simple CASE statement. But it's static and doesn't grow with additional breaks that may come in. CASE WHEN Between B1Start and B1End then 0 WHEN Between B2Start and B2End THEN 0 else 1 END

Comment: OK, as mentioned: a Join on the breaks table should solve the problem and works for all breaks (all and new ones) in the corresponding tables.